# how to create a new bar chart using the data from the existing barcharts

Tags: dataset, charts

I have the following code to generate two separate bar charts. I like to create a new bar chart by extracting the data from the following barcharts.

```
bc1 = BarChart[
   <|"Cambodia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 75.4, "Urban" -> 61.9, 
      "Rural" -> 77.7|>,
    "Indonesia-May" -> <|"National" -> 79.8, "Urban" -> 78.7, 
      "Rural" -> 81.8|>,
    "Lao PDR-Jul" -> <|"National" -> 27.0, "Urban" -> 28.8, 
      "Rural" -> 26.0|>,
    "Mongolia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 17.5, "Urban" -> 19.3, 
      "Rural" -> 14.1|>, 
    "Myanmar-Oct" -> <|"National" -> 52.8, "Urban" -> 54.9, 
      "Rural" -> 51.7|>,
    "Philippines-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 75.8, "Urban" -> 78.4, 
      "Rural" -> 72.9|>, 
    "Solomon Islands-Jun" -> <|"National" -> 32.3, "Urban" -> 33.1, 
      "Rural" -> 32.2|>|>,
   ChartLabels -> {{"Cambodia\nDec", "Indonesia\nMay", "Lao PDR\nJul",
       "Mongolia\nDec", "Myanmar\nOct", "Philippines\nDec", 
      "Solomon Isl.\nJun"}, None},
   ChartLegends -> Placed[{"National", "Urban", "Rural"}, Below],
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   PlotLabel -> "Factor 1",
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},
   FrameLabel -> {None, "% of households"},
   BarSpacing -> None
   ];

bc2 = BarChart[
   <|"Cambodia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 555.4, "Urban" -> 40, 
      "Rural" -> 80|>,
    "Indonesia-May" -> <|"National" -> 25.8, "Urban" -> 80, 
      "Rural" -> 81.8|>,
    "Lao PDR-Jul" -> <|"National" -> 27.0, "Urban" -> 45, 
      "Rural" -> 26.0|>,
    "Mongolia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 17.5, "Urban" -> 30, 
      "Rural" -> 14.1|>,
    "Myanmar-Oct" -> <|"National" -> 52.8, "Urban" -> 54.9, 
      "Rural" -> 51.7|>,
    "Philippines-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 40, "Urban" -> 25, 
      "Rural" -> 72.9|>,
    "Solomon Islands-Jun" -> <|"National" -> 32.3, "Urban" -> 33.1, 
      "Rural" -> 32.2|>|>,
   ChartLabels -> {{"Cambodia\nDec", "Indonesia\nMay", "Lao PDR\nJul",
       "Mongolia\nDec", "Myanmar\nOct", "Philippines\nDec", 
      "Solomon Isl.\nJun"}, None},
   ChartLegends -> Placed[{"National", "Urban", "Rural"}, Below],
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   PlotLabel -> "Factor 2",
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},
   FrameLabel -> {None, "% of households"},
   BarSpacing -> None
   ];
```

If I want to create a new bar chart only for Cambodia, for example, I will have to extract the Cambodia data from each bar chart manually, which I do not want to do because I have many bar charts to do this operation. Rather I like to do the data extraction using Mathematica and create the new bar chart desired.

Comment: I've been digging to the `FullForm` of `bc1` and it doesn't look as if the data can be easily extracted from the plot.

Comment: @mikado: I did not mean extracting the data from the plot. Below, please see the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the data from the bar charts.

```
data1 = <|"Cambodia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 75.4, "Urban" -> 61.9, 
     "Rural" -> 77.7|>, 
   "Indonesia-May" -> <|"National" -> 79.8, "Urban" -> 78.7, "Rural" -> 81.8|>,
    "Lao PDR-Jul" -> <|"National" -> 27.0, "Urban" -> 28.8, "Rural" -> 26.0|>,
    "Mongolia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 17.5, "Urban" -> 19.3, "Rural" -> 14.1|>,
    "Myanmar-Oct" -> <|"National" -> 52.8, "Urban" -> 54.9, "Rural" -> 51.7|>,
    "Philippines-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 75.8, "Urban" -> 78.4, 
     "Rural" -> 72.9|>, 
   "Solomon Islands-Jun" -> <|"National" -> 32.3, "Urban" -> 33.1, 
     "Rural" -> 32.2|>|>;

data2 = <|"Cambodia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 555.4, "Urban" -> 40, 
     "Rural" -> 80|>, 
   "Indonesia-May" -> <|"National" -> 25.8, "Urban" -> 80, "Rural" -> 81.8|>, 
   "Lao PDR-Jul" -> <|"National" -> 27.0, "Urban" -> 45, "Rural" -> 26.0|>, 
   "Mongolia-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 17.5, "Urban" -> 30, "Rural" -> 14.1|>, 
   "Myanmar-Oct" -> <|"National" -> 52.8, "Urban" -> 54.9, "Rural" -> 51.7|>, 
   "Philippines-Dec" -> <|"National" -> 40, "Urban" -> 25, "Rural" -> 72.9|>, 
   "Solomon Islands-Jun" -> <|"National" -> 32.3, "Urban" -> 33.1, 
     "Rural" -> 32.2|>|>;

BarChart[{data1[#], data2[#]},
   ChartLabels -> {{"Factor1", "Factor2"}, None},
   PlotLabel -> #,
   ChartLegends -> Placed[
     {"National", "Urban", "Rural"}, Below]] &@
 "Cambodia-Dec"
```

[image]

Or with "Log" scaling

```
BarChart[{data1[#], data2[#]},
   ChartLabels -> {{"Factor1", "Factor2"}, None},
   PlotLabel -> #,
   ChartLegends -> Placed[
     {"National", "Urban", "Rural"}, Below],
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log"] &@
 "Cambodia-Dec"
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to selectively view data

```
keys = Keys[data1];
```

**EDIT 2:** Added export button (edit file path to your desired location)

keys = Keys[data1];

```
Manipulate[
 barchart = BarChart[{data1[#], data2[#]},
     ChartLabels -> {
       {Tooltip["Factor1", Dataset[data1]],
        Tooltip["Factor2", Dataset[data2]]}, None},
     PlotLabel -> Dataset[<|
        <|"Factor1" -> data1[#]|>,
        <|"Factor2" -> data2[#]|>|>],
     ChartLegends -> Placed[
       {"National", "Urban", "Rural"}, Below]] &[key],
 Row[{
   Control[{{key, keys[[1]]}, keys}],
   Spacer[150],
   Button["Export",
    Export[
     "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/BarCharts/" <>
      key <> 
      ".jpg", barchart]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Manipulate` is a very good tool. When I run `Manipulate` for Cambodia, for example, and if I want to save the bar char generated as `png` or `jpeg` into my hard disk, how do I do that? Thank you very much.